# Sending emails using Mailgun with NodeMailer package

Tags: node.js, mailgun, nodemailer

A couple of days ago I realized that Google has changed the security of gmail accounts, particularly for the possibility of sending emails from applications. After Googling around for a while I couldn't find a fix for it.
So, I resorted to using Mailgun. I created an account and had it enabled with Business verification. However, I still can't send emails. I keep getting an error about the requested URL not being found.
I am suspecting that since I haven't set up a domain yet, it is not picking the mailgun domain it provided by default. Could someone show me how to test sending emails using Mailgun from NodeMailer indicating the sandbox name provided by mailgun.

thanks in advance
José

Answer (score 38):

```
var nodemailer = require('nodemailer');
// send mail with password confirmation
var transporter = nodemailer.createTransport( {
    service:  'Mailgun',
    auth: {
     user: 'postmaster@sandboxXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX.mailgun.org',
     pass: 'XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX'   
    }
});
var mailOpts = {
    from: 'office@yourdomain.com',
    to: 'user@gmail.com',
    subject: 'test subject',
    text : 'test message form mailgun',
    html : '<b>test message form mailgun</b>'
};
transporter.sendMail(mailOpts, function (err, response) {
    if (err) {
     //ret.message = "Mail error.";
    } else {
     //ret.message = "Mail send.";
    }
});
```

Comment: when would I use this over the api_key/domain auth? or is it an either/or

Comment: Just what I was looking! Don't want to use `api_key` since is tied to many accounts of different projects. Highly insecure!

Comment: @Sebastialonso Can you explain more about why it's insecure?

Comment: Well because anyone can see the password. and can access or do anything with the account like that.

Answer (score 34):

I created the [Nodemailer transport for mailgun](https://github.com/orliesaurus/nodemailer-mailgun-transport).

Here it how it works.

You install the package with `npm install` as you would do with any package, then in an empty file:

```
var nodemailer = require('nodemailer');
var mg = require('nodemailer-mailgun-transport');

// This is your API key that you retrieve from www.mailgun.com/cp (free up to 10K monthly emails)
var auth = {
  auth: {
    api_key: 'key-1234123412341234',
    domain: 'sandbox3249234.mailgun.org'
  }
}

var nodemailerMailgun = nodemailer.createTransport(mg(auth));

nodemailerMailgun.sendMail({
  from: 'myemail@example.com',
  to: 'recipient@domain.com', // An array if you have multiple recipients.
  subject: 'Hey you, awesome!',
  text: 'Mailgun rocks, pow pow!',
}, function (err, info) {
  if (err) {
    console.log('Error: ' + err);
  }
  else {
    console.log('Response: ' + info);
  }
});
```

Replace your API key with yours and change the details and you're ready to go!

Comment: pay attention with this 'nodemailer-mailgun-transport' it impossible to add nodemailer's icalEvent  to email messages (https://nodemailer.com/message/calendar-events/#1-send-a-request-event-as-a-string),
 it is bertter to use nodemailer.createTransport(...) in order to do that.

Comment: Is that domain made up or ?

Answer (score 1):

It worked me, when I added the domain also to the auth object (not only the api_key). Like this:

```
var auth = {
  auth: {
    api_key: 'key-12319312391',
    domain: 'sandbox3249234.mailgun.org'
  }
};
```